# On my iPad, how can I tell if a website is secure on Safari?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, security

Does the web address have to be in green, or is it secure if it's in black?

Answer (score 4):

If the site is being accessed over HTTPS, then the lock icon is shown (in black).

If the HTTPS certificate has been verified, the lock icon is shown in green.

---

Both are secure, however the latter vouches for the authenticity of the site as well as the security of the connection.

For example:

- https://www.icloud.com/ shows a **green** lock icon, having been verified as Apple Inc.

  [image: iCloud verified as being owned by Apple Inc. in Cupertino, California, US]
- https://georgegarside.com/blog/ shows a **black** lock icon. Even though it's secure over HTTPS, it hasn't been verified.

  [image: George Garside's Blog not verified]

You can visit the two links on your iPad to see the difference in lock icon.

Comment: A black lock does indicate verification; it just hasn't been verified as rigorously as a a green icon.  If a site hasn't been verified but requests a secure connection, Safari won't let you connect.